# How to make "wrap_content" work after altering content in Android Motion Layout?

Tags: android, textview, android-motionlayout, android-wrap-content

The 'wrap_content' not work properly in MotionLayout when setting a new value.
I created a sample with a TextView above RecyclerView.
The TextView was set to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and `android:text='Hello World!` at first. 
Then `TextView#setText()` will be called after fetching content from the server.
So my question is that the TextView height won't change after I set some very long text.

I am using `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha4`.
Here is the sample code:

MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.paranoid.mao.motionlayoutwrapcontentexp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import kotlin.concurrent.thread

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val dummyItems = List(100) { "Item: $it" }
    private val longText = "Wrap content \nnot works!"
    private lateinit var header: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        header = findViewById(R.id.header)
        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler)
        recyclerView.adapter = MyAdapter()

        // set immediately will work fine
        // header.text = longText

        // set with some delay won't show properly
        simulateLoadFromRemote()
    }

    private fun simulateLoadFromRemote() {
        thread {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1)
            runOnUiThread {
                header.text = longText
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/scene_activity_main"
    tools:motionProgress="0"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="48dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

scene_activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/end">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@id/recycler"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="top"/>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleX="1"
            android:scaleY="1"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        </Constraint>

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleX="0.5"
            android:scaleY="0.5"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent">
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

Expected:
https://ibb.co/zR7Pq8V

Actual:
https://ibb.co/QdLkJQX

**Update**:`implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3` doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Did you even find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Any solution? This is still the case for me in version 2.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you were able to solve this issue, but in the transition tag of the scene description XML, you can always inform it to honor requests. Something like this;

```
<Transition
    motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
    motion:layoutDuringTransition="honorRequest"
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/end">
    <OnSwipe
        motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
        motion:touchAnchorId="@id/recycler"
        motion:touchAnchorSide="top"/>
</Transition>
```

For me it worked whenever I had items that were of varying heights within the MotionLayout content.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this issue seem like resolved at latest version `2.0.0-beta7`

Comment: back again in `2.0.1`

Comment: still in version 2.0.4

Comment: 2.1.0-beta01 seems to have the same issue too